# Random values after transformation from character to integer

Tags: r, dplyr

I would transform values in a dataframe's column, in which there are 20 different values, from strings (`character`) to `integer`. 
I have tried to apply `as.integer(as.factor(col_values))`, but after this transformation I get completely random integer values (`levels = 1251, 89, 126, ...`), instead, I would get something like `1, 2,3, ..., 20`.

Comment: You may need `as.integer(factor(col_values, levels = unique(col_values)))`

Comment: If it is already a character vector (not a factor) you might want to skip the factor and just use as.integer. Factors are stored as integer codes; it sounds like you are creating the “random” integers by converting it to a factor.

Comment: @joran I have tried, but I get an NA by coercion: `NAs introduced by coercion”Warning message in evalq(as.numeric(col_values), <environment>)`, How could I avoid this issue?

Comment: That means you have things in the vector that are not sensible integers. Letters or ambiguous punctuation. You’ll need to remove them via something like gsub()

Comment: To follow on from @joran - this will retain only digits a given character vector `str`: `gsub("[^0-9]", "", str)`.

Comment: The SO R FAQ heartily suggests using `dput()` to include your data so others can help you.